# how use primefaces and prettyfaces together?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, prettyfaces

Primefaces doesn't work when primefaces and pretty face use together.
I add flowing jar:

```
prettyfaces-jsf2-3.3.3.jar
primefaces-4.0-20130605.174828-3.jar
```

My web.xml code:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>Pretty Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping> 
    <filter-name>Pretty Filter</filter-name> 
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher> 
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher> 
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

My pretty-config.xml code:

```
<rewrite match="^[^(/primefaces_resource/)|^(javascript)]" trailingSlash="append"  toCase="lowercase" redirect="301"/>
<url-mapping id="home"> 
    <pattern value="/" /> 
    <view-id value="/" />
</url-mapping>
```

This image is whithou prittyface( jar and configure):
[image]

when I add pretty face jar .then flowing view:
[image]

I want to change the url.

example:

```
  (http://localhost:8084/AntSchoolMS/faces/index.xhtml)
```

I want it to be changed as

```
(http://localhost:8084/AntSchoolMS/)
```

please help me .

Comment: I'm sorry, but what exactly are we to deduce from the two pictures? What is the result you're expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use primefaces 3.5 with pretty faces 3.3.3 and works ok. The configuration in your web.xml seems to be ok. Make sure you place pretty-config.xml also in WEB-INF.
About the pretty-config you posted: it doesn't make any sense to have a url-mapping where the pattern and the view-id are the same, so remove it. 
Also I don't have that rewrite rule, I have several mappings like the folowing:

```
<url-mapping id="login">
    <pattern value="/login/">
    <view-id value="/login.jsf" />
</url-mapping>
```

Did you try removing that rewrite rule to see what happens?

Answer (score 1):

I've been using these two for some time and they are working as expected. My project used the 3.5 version of primefaces and PrettyFaces 3.3.3.

In my web.xml I did not need to register any filter like you did.

I would also try to remove the rewrite rule as Damian suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, I would recommend upgrading to the latest version of PrettyFaces - see http://ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/